# Cut-off frequency in simulation does not match calculation

Tags: simulation, signal-processing, low-pass, active-filter, cutoff-frequency

I am an engineering student currently learning how to design low-pass active filters. Currently, I am having trouble matching my calculations with the simulation values. My design has the following parameters: fc = 250 Hz, Q = 0.70 (Butterworth approx.). My current circuit is shown below:

[image]

I am using Multisim for conducting an AC sweep analysis to see the frequency response of the circuit. The response is shown below:

[image]

Using the formula ½·π·R·C (R1=R2, C1=C2), I calculated the resistor value choosing 47 nF initially.

Supposedly, it should have fc = 250 Hz based on the equation. Based on the simulation, the -3dB point is already beyond that (x2 = 359, y2 = -3dB). I used the gain 1.588dB, which is the approx. value for a Butterworth filter, and calculated for R3 with 10 kΩ chosen Rf value.

Am I missing something here? Is there a design consideration I am missing?

Comment: The resistors are correct for gain = 1.588, not 1.588 dB. (So, about 4dB, do the math yourself). So, at what frequency is the gain about 1 dB? 250Hz? It's doing what you expect then.

Comment: Hi. The frequency is approx. 250 Hz. I also observed this awhile ago, but didn't really understand why or couldn't explain if its probably the gain's fault.

Comment: Perhaps that is a non-ideal op-amp, which has finite slew rate and bandwidth? Is there an ideal op-amp in the simulator you can try?

Comment: @Elmark Corpus I wondered if you've actually understood Brian's comment? The cut off frequency is defined as being 3dB down from the pass band. The gain in the pass band is +4dB. Therefore at the true cut-off frequency, the gain will be +4dB - 3dB = 1dB. You are actually assuming the cut-off frequency is where the gain is 7dB down from the pass band.

Comment: @James, thank you for clarifying. I actually didn't understood it at first.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, first of all it is not very hard to find the transfer function of this circuit. But I will use the result from [Okawa Electric Design](http://sim.okawa-denshi.jp/en/OPseikiLowkeisan.htm):

$$\mathscr{H}\left(\text{s}\right):=\frac{\text{v}_\text{out}\left(\text{s}\right)}{\text{v}_\text{in}\left(\text{s}\right)}=\frac{\frac{\text{G}}{\text{C}_1\text{C}_2\text{R}_1\text{R}_2}}{\text{s}^2+\left(\frac{1}{\text{C}_1\text{R}_1}+\frac{1}{\text{C}_1\text{R}_2}+\frac{1-\text{G}}{\text{C}_2\text{R}_2}\right)\text{s}+\frac{1}{\text{C}_1\text{C}_2\text{R}_1\text{R}_2}}\tag1$$

Where \$\text{G}:=1+\frac{\text{R}_4}{\text{R}_3}\$.

And the circuit is given by:

[image]

Using your values, we can see that:

$$\mathscr{H}\left(\text{s}\right)=\frac{1080000000000000000}{381969\text{s}(721497\text{s}+1600000000)+680000000000000000}\tag2$$

Now, we can find the cut-off frequency \$\omega_0\$ by finding:

$$\left|\underline{\mathscr{H}}\left(\text{j}\omega_0\right)\right|=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\cdot\left|\underline{\hat{\mathscr{H}}}\left(\text{j}\omega\right)\right|\tag3$$

This leads to:

$$\omega_0=\frac{200000000 \sqrt{24 \sqrt{145}+1}}{2164491}\approx1573.52\space\text{rad/sec}\tag4$$

In Hertz, this gives:

$$\text{f}_0=\frac{100000000 \sqrt{24 \sqrt{145}+1}}{2164491 \pi }\approx250.433\space\text{Hz}\tag5$$

I found that last result, by using the following Mathematica-code:

```
In[1]:=Clear["Global`*"];
G = 1 + (R4/R3);
R1 = 13545;
R2 = 13545;
R3 = 17000;
R4 = 10000;
C1 = 47*10^(-9);
C2 = 47*10^(-9);
s = I*2*Pi*f;
x = ((G)/(C1*C2*R1*
       R2))/(s^2 + ((1/(C1*R1)) + (1/(C1*R2)) + ((1 - G)/(C2*R2)))*
      s + (1/(C1*C2*R1*R2)));
y = FullSimplify[
   Sqrt[ComplexExpand[Re[x]]^2 + ComplexExpand[Im[x]]^2]];
solution = FullSimplify[Solve[{D[y, f] == 0, f > 0}, f]];
solutionForF = f /. solution[[1]];
n = Solve[{y == (1/Sqrt[2])*Limit[y, f -> solutionForF], f > 0}, f];
Flatten[n] && Flatten[N[n]]

Out[1]={f -> (100000000 Sqrt[1 + 24 Sqrt[145]])/(2164491 \[Pi])} && {f -> 
   250.433}
```

Comment: As we can see from the transfer function (general form) the pole frequency is 1/SQRT(R1R2C1C2). On the other hand, for Butterworth responses we know that wp=wc. Hence, for equal componenets: wc=1/RC.

Comment: The OP had already calculated the expected frequency response, that was not the question. The question was how to **interpret the plot** produced by the simulation, which Brian Drummond answered correctly over a month ago.

Answer (score -1):

I frequently make a very accurate Butterworth lowpass filter with a gain of 1 like this:
[image: Butterworth]